# Get source instance behind the selected DataGrid row

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in xaml and I populate it by setting the ItemsSource like this

```
var myList = new List<Product>();
//Product is a standard class created for the purpose of populating the datagrid

 myList.Add(new Product(){Name = "bla", SerialNumber = 1234})
 myList.Add(new Product(){Name = "somename", SerialNumber = 567})

dataGrid.ItemsSource = myList;
```

So basically each row in the datagrid is populated with values from an instance of the Product class.

Later in the code when the user selects a row in the datagrid and presses a key, I get the  selected row like this

```
dataGrid.SelectedItem
```

But now, I cant seem to figure out how to get the Product instance which was used to create that selected row.

So for example something like var test = dataGrid.SelectedItem.Instance which would be the same as doing this this var test = new Product(){Name = "bla", SerialNumber = 1234}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dataGrid.SelectedItem` property *should* return your `Product` instance, but if you do have a `DataGridRow` object, then you can get the related data item using the [`DataGridRow.Item` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridrow.item%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
 Product selectedProduct = (Product)yourDataGridRow.Item;
```

Comment: Oh of course I need to cast the selected item into Product before I use it, I haven't realized that.

Comment: Yeah, the `DataGridRow.Item` Property is of type `object`.